# App with access to directories outside the SandBox. Root access

Tags: sandbox, root, jailbreak, cydia

I'm creating an app for the iPhone (Jailbreak). Said app modifies this directory (among others) "/Ringtones.PQNYRJ/", trying to create a ringtone file. The thing is that I've tried it every possible way and I can't get it to work. I've followed the Cydia's documentation and I've made a file with the same name as the app but with a shell script to execute the binary (renamed with an underscore).

```
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/MyTones_ "$@" 2>>/tmp/MyTones.log
```

I've set the proper permissions (or so I think)... I've based them off of Cydia.app permissions and all I got back is:

> AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-3000 "Cannot create file"
>   UserInfo=0xa79750
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0xa79860 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (OSStatus error -12115.)",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create
>   file}

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't about the error, but i'll just list everything i did, successfully.

- chmod the run script to 755 (obvious)
- chmod the app binary to 4755 and chown to 0:0 (root)
- Setup the Info.plist to launch the run script, not app binary (again, obvious)
- Try changing your script to just: (log file not strictly necessary)
  *dir=$(dirname "$0")
  exec "${dir}"/AppBinary*

That's everything i did, and it works perfectly.

Of course, we're talking Jailbroken here, Apple would never allow this in the AppStore.

Comment: Thank's, but not works. The path is /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ . <Warning>: AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3000 "Cannot create file" UserInfo=0xa77e60 {NSUnderlyingError=0xa61d00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12115.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file}